# Am I a employee or freelance?

Tags: united-kingdom, freelancing, bullying

If you work anywhere full time, 5 days a week from 10am to 6pm and found on a website that you should be a fully contracted member of staff by law and that the boss should be paying tax and other things such as sick play what should you do and what if asking would get you fired with no notice or reference.

Comment: Your rights are in your contract, if they appear to favour your employer unrealistically and put you at an unfair disadvantage, it is likely to be arguable that they are mistreating you, the line about not telling anybody or get fired would be more than enough, I suggest requesting a meeting and having a witness (as you are allowed) and make a record of everything said, this is the only way you can improve your situation, saying nothing will change nothing.

Comment: Per your comment to an answer, that you invoice the employer for the amount they are to pay you, you are freelance (almost certainly a Sole Trader) and *you* are responsible for paying your tax and other items. You need to get advice immediately from an Accountant.

Comment: It sounds like your employer was deceptive to you about your situation. If you ask a simple tax question but get treated like that you need to find some serious outside legal advice and—sadly to say—possibly a new job. If they simply did not pay taxes for your wages that just means you were a freelancer/per-hour worker; not ideal but not great. If they were withholding taxes but won’t work with you, they are really ripping you off and cheating the system. Either way, seek legal advice and document all interactions with your employers and their representatives. Best of luck!

Comment: @MarvMills Wouldn't there be restrictions on what the employer can demand of a freelancer though, similar to the US model where companies can't just claim someone is a contractor when they micro-manage that person's time and tasks?

Comment: @Lilienthal In the UK you can be *either* a 'Permanent' employee, where the employer (which might be a company you own and run) deals with your tax and other deductibles, or you are 'Self-Employed', where you are responsible for your own tax affairs and bill the company for the amounts they owe you. It is not something that can be switched at will. If you are Permanent you have a Contract of Employment stating terms. If you are Self-Employed you will only have a contract for delivery of billable services (much simplification here!)

Comment: @MarvMills I appreciate the short version :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workplace can't give out legal advice, however the first thing I would do is re-read through my contract and see how (if at all) it applies to the current situation.

Then I would personally contact the Citezen's Advice Bureau, they will be able to tell you what you should and should not be doing and may be able to point you to material that will advise you further.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Advice like this can be given in the comments.

Comment: @Lilienthal, wanting to help someone wether it is in comments or in an answer, that is all that matters.

Comment: Thanks jake but it's not cash in hand.  she tells us how much she will pay us that week and we invoice her so she gets tax deducted

Comment: @Dansmith Helping a specific user is not the goal of the StackExchange network, the goal is to build sites that collect useful Q&A that will be helpful to multiple people. Off-topic help can be given in the comments or on chat without ignoring the site's criteria for on-topic questions. Upvoted answers prevent the automatic clean-up of closed questions which pollutes the site. Users bad questions in good fatih is one of the major reasons why currently a full quarter of our 9K questions are closed but still on the site.

Comment: @Lilienthal that is closed minded, how can you be 10000% sure that the answer will not help somebody else besides the OP?

Comment: +1 for the Citizens Advice Bureau. They have lawyers who specialize in employment law and offer excellent, free advice.

Comment: @Dansmith The point is that the question is not a useful one for the site because we don't need hundreds of unique questions with each having a handful of answers saying "I can't answer but call a lawyer or government agency X". That's precisely why close votes exist and why users shouldn't answer questions they know to be off-topic. It's a rather cheap way of harvesting reputation, complicates cleanup efforts and gives others the impression that they can just ask their own off-topic question because someone will be *kind* enough to answer before it's closed.

Comment: Wow! I'm really sorry I just had a work related question and needed help. Lilienthal I really didn't mean to upset the way you run the site

Comment: @Kialandei True, but you also mentioned that "the workplace can't give out legal advice" which prompted my original comment.

Comment: @Lilienthal Yeah I realised that afterwards, I'll make sure to reply as a comment in future instances.

Comment: @fashionworker Please don't think that I'm upset or that you did anything wrong. It's perfectly understandable that you would ask your question here. We often get questions that aren't a great fit for our Q&A format which is why we end up closing them. In this case, it was closed because you asked about your legal rights which is a topic too complex for random people on the internet to answer. A more general question on the criteria for qualifying as an employee or a freelancer in the UK would probably be on-topic as it doesn't require an *interpretation of the law*.

Comment: That's absolutely fine and fair enough thank you. Iv never used anything like this before and felt I started a bit of a debate/upset

Comment: But thank you all for your help. I feel iv been pointed in the right direction and will look into it a lot more with HM R&C